# Xaml ResourceKey as a variable not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, variables, resources

I'm using a ComboBox (WPF 4.0) to show user defined paragraph styles for an editor app. The ComboBox has two columns:

(1) Name of the paragraph style

(2) Text "abcABC123", should in some properties be formatted according to the paragraph style in the first column

(1) is working, (2) is not because _ResourceKey_background, _ResourceKey_foreground and _ResourceKey_fontFamily are no ResourceKeys 
but variables containing ResourceKeys. How can I solve this?

_NameInternal, _NameUI, _ResourceKey_background, _ResourceKey_foreground and _ResourceKey_fontFamily are public properties 
of the user defined paragraph style class.

```
<ComboBox Name="_cbStylesPara" SelectedValuePath="_NameInternal"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _collectionViewSource_stylesPara}}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding _NameUI}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="abcABC123" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Background="{DynamicResource _ResourceKey_background}"
                           Foreground="{DynamicResource _ResourceKey_foreground}"
                           FontFamily="{DynamicResource _ResourceKey_fontFamily}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Where these resources located? In your App resources or in window resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As like you said resources are declared under App resources, what you can do is create an [**IValueConverter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and return the resource value from it's Convert method.

```
public class ResouceLookupConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return App.Current.TryFindResource(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

*XAML*:

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.Resources>
     <local:ResouceLookupConverter x:Key="ResouceLookupConverter"/>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
  ......
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="abcABC123" Margin="3,0,0,0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Background="{Binding _ResourceKey_background,
                          Converter={StaticResource ResouceLookupConverter}}"
             Foreground="{Binding _ResourceKey_foreground,
                          Converter={StaticResource ResouceLookupConverter}}"
             FontFamily="{Binding _ResourceKey_fontFamily,
                          Converter={StaticResource ResouceLookupConverter}}" />
</ComboBox>
```

***Note***: Ofcourse you have to define local namespace in your XAML set to the namespace where your Converter is declared.